# Betti's number and homology with integer coefficients

Tags: algebraic-topology, lie-groups, homology-cohomology, geometric-topology, betti-numbers

I don't know how to prove the following observation.

> Take $G$ a connected Lie group such that $H^1(G,\mathbb{R})=0$ so the Betti's number is zero and this implies that $H^{1}(G,\mathbb{Z})$ is finite.

Can anyone help me?

thanks in advance

Comment: Do you know the [Universal Coefficient Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_coefficient_theorem#Universal_coefficient_theorem_for_cohomology)?

Comment: No I didn't, but I've found out it just few minutes ago... Thank you

Comment: Also, could you add some more context to your question? For example, where have you seen this claimed?

Comment: I saw it in a demonstration of semisimple compact connected lie group has finite foundamental group.  But the universal coefficient theorem is the right tool, with it I can prove the fact